# Express.js - hit url to download file from api

Tags: javascript, express, shopify

I am working with shopify admin api. I create a bulk operation and in return it gives me a url. When you hit this url it automatically downloads the file. This file as information that my server needs.

So where I am at - I send the request for bulk operation, then I hit the url to download file and file gets downloaded by my browser.

What I need is to hit the url, and then download and save the file into a folder on my server where I can then start working with it. And I dont know how to do this, I tried, I looked around. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

My code:

```
app.get("/postBulkProds", async (req,res) => {
  let url = GRAPHQL_CUSTOM_URL;
  await fetch(url, postBulkProducts())
    .then(res=> res.json())  
    .then(bulk => res.send(bulk))
    .catch(error => res.send(error));
});


app.get("/getBulkProds", async(req,res, next) => {
  let data;
  let url = GRAPHQL_CUSTOM_URL;
  await fetch(url, getBulkProducts())
    .then(products=> (products.json(products)))  
    .then(products => (data = products))
    .catch(error => res.send(error));
    console.log(data.data.currentBulkOperation.url);
    res.locals.bulk = data;
    let url2 = data.data.currentBulkOperation.url;
    res.redirect(url2);
});
```

EDIT-SOLVED

```
fetch(url2)
    .then(r => r.text())
    //.then( t=> console.log(t))
    .then(t => {let json=JSON.stringify(t);
      //console.log(json);
      fs.writeFile('./myfile.jsonl', json, err => {
        if(err){
          console.log("error writing", err);
        } else {
          console.log("success");
        }
      })
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```